# My bootstrap 5 carousel controls make my checkbox not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel, bootstrap-5

I used a Bootstrap carousel with a simple form inside.

The problem is that the input `:my_miss_france_guess` is not working since I added the bootstrap carousel elements..

When I click on it, it shows the previous slide instead of checking the checkbox.

It's really weird because the submit button works.

Do you know why?

Here is my code:

```
<%= form_tag new_year_myfifteen_path(@year), method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories, @selected_category), include_blank: 'Select category' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
<% end %>

  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @misses.each do |miss| %>
      <div class="carousel-item <%= 'active' if miss == @misses.first %>">
        <div class="avatar-item">
          <%= miss.region %>
          <%= image_tag "#{miss.photo}.jpg"%>
          <%= simple_form_for([@year, @myfifteen]) do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :my_miss_france_guess, as: :boolean, label: "C'est elle la Miss France!" %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :miss_id, value: miss.id %>
          <%= f.button :submit, "Valider" %>
    <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And his is the the rendered HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modale">
  <h1>Choisir une miss</h1>
  
  <form action="/years/38/myfifteens/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
    <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="">Select category</option>
      <option value="bombe">bombe</option>
      <option value="mignonne">mignonne</option>
      <option value="pas ouf">pas ouf</option>
      <option value="non">deg</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" data-disable-with="Filter">
  </form>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

  <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="avatar-item">
          Bourgogne
          <img src="/assets/bourgogne-218db68fd276a3374ef4ca7dd80b28be22a47cf3c1ac0de95f4a94ec1f96ab18.jpeg">
          <form class="simple_form new_myfifteen" id="new_myfifteen" novalidate="novalidate" action="/years/38/myfifteens" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="hJOBftfkxLDWs7nlIrgol_KeHbeIdhxndMl0LvbUL3x2FSe28CoylrdwvejKOAyY4Adr9dEA06I1oXIYJujrfA" autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset class="mb-3 boolean optional myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
              <div class="form-check"><input name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off"><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" id="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
                <label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">C'est elle la Miss France!</label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input value="199" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="myfifteen[miss_id]" id="myfifteen_miss_id">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Valider" class="btn" data-disable-with="Valider">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <div class="avatar-item">Aquitaine<img src="/assets/Aquitaine-d7b594dfaf68d56abedad683073287ce77c06fc7b7f51f4f3515a220695107ec.jpeg">
          <form class="simple_form new_myfifteen" id="new_myfifteen" novalidate="novalidate" action="/years/38/myfifteens" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="6mv9FsqiyPng04h_zZlmYnmIDP2Za2SwAAPnjjvE8HgY7Vve7Ww-34EQjHIlGUJtaxF6v8Adq3VBa-G46_g0eA" autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset class="mb-3 boolean optional myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
              <div class="form-check"><input name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off"><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" id="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
                <label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">C'est elle la Miss France!</label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input value="200" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="myfifteen[miss_id]" id="myfifteen_miss_id">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Valider" class="btn" data-disable-with="Valider">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <div class="avatar-item">Bretagne<img src="/assets/Bretagne-7ee355d04d53538e218043f2e557f1bdb9a975089961604b18afe185b4502dc3.jpeg">
          <form class="simple_form new_myfifteen" id="new_myfifteen" novalidate="novalidate" action="/years/38/myfifteens" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="-Yczz6XUSXy1HwYx2E5oIu5PLALXymSjRqXtANTgk84LAZUHghq_WtTcAjwwzkwt_NZaQI68q2YHzes2BNxXzg" autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset class="mb-3 boolean optional myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
              <div class="form-check"><input name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off"><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="myfifteen[my_miss_france_guess]" id="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">
                <label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="myfifteen_my_miss_france_guess">C'est elle la Miss France!</label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input value="203" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="myfifteen[miss_id]" id="myfifteen_miss_id">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Valider" class="btn" data-disable-with="Valider">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've positioned your form content behind the carousel controls. Either disable them and use custom controls, reposition them, or put padding on your carousel slides to bring your content inward, out from under the controls.